# How to prove differentiability for general case for such function

Tags: derivatives

How do I prove that $\dfrac {|a| x \Bbb e ^x} {|b| - \Bbb e ^x + |c|}$ is differentiable, where $a,b,c$ are arbitrary values such that $|b| + |c| \ne \Bbb e^x$?

I tried doing the $\lim _{h \to 0}$ methods to prove it is differentiable for any arbitrary value $u$, i.e. $\lim _{h \to 0} \frac {f(u+h) -f(u)} h$ but it becomes very tedious.

I wonder if there are any other methods we can prove it mathematically? Else, I have to just say since it is an elementary function, thus it is differentiable?

Thank you all!

Comment: Do you know the product, quotient rules?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. Yes I know, but it helps?

Comment: A "rational expression" built from differentiable functions is differentiable wherever it s defined.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. Yes, but is there any way I can prove it mathematically? Like taking the limits or using epislon delta definition to prove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product rule: If $f,g$ are differentiable at $x$ then so is the
function $\phi(x) = f(x)g(x)$ and $\phi'(x) = f'(x) g(x) + f(x) g'(x)$.

Quotient rule: If $f,g$ are differentiable at $x$, and
$g(x) \neq 0$, then so is the
function $\phi(x) = {f(x) \over g(x)}$ and $\phi'(x) = {f'(x) g(x) - f(x) g'(x) \over g(x)^2}$.

In your case, $f(x) = |a| x e^{x}$, and applying the product rule gives
$f'(x) = |a| x e^{x} + |a| e^{x}$. We have
$g(x) = |b|+|c| -e^x$, and so $g'(x) = - e^x$.

Now substitute into the quotient rule to get the answer.